# Nextjs accessign router.query when the page in unmounting

Tags: next.js

I have a nextjs application in which I have a dynamic routed page `information/[...sections].js`. In this page I am extracting the query information like:
`const [page, ...info] = router.query.sections;`.

Everything works fine, but when I use a link tag to go to another page, lets say `index.js` page, the app breaks and gives me an error saying `Cannot iterate on sections` (because sections becomes undefined). At this point, even the url is `http://localhost:3000/`, so why is it accessing the `information/[...sections].js` page code.